# SO profile page taking forever to load

Tags: support

Every other page on SO is loading fine except for the user profile page.  It goes blank for more than 30 seconds before the content shows up.  It's a repeatable problem and has only been happening today.

However, the Meta profile page loads instantly as does every other page on SO and Meta.

Comment: Seems like the CDN is having issues.  Interestingly, the meta profile has no such issue...

Comment: MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240423/no-css-on-any-stackexchange-com-sites-except-meta

Comment: Sooo what now? I should get back to work, I guess?

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: Yes, confirmed, just started working.

Answer (score 1):

As per a comment, the CDN was having issues loading CSS assets.

[No CSS on any *.stackexchange.com sites, except meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240423/no-css-on-any-stackexchange-com-sites-except-meta)

However, not sure why it was only affecting profile pages.

Seems to be fixed now.